# Mixed page orientation in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm developing my first application with *Vaadin* and *JasperReports*. I have the following trouble, i have to extract a .rtf document that is composed in this way:

The first page has to have an vertical orientation while the second one has to have an horizontal orientation

Now I'm trying to solve this problem in this way:

```
    JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(pathFirstJrxml ,pathFirstJasper );  
    JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(pathSecondJrxml ,pathSecondJasper ); 

    File fileFirstReport = new File(pathFirstJasper);
    File fileSecondReport = new File(pathSecondJasper);

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport((JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(fileFirstReport),null,dataSourceFirstReport);
    JasperPrint jasperPrintSubReport = JasperFillManager.fillReport((JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(fileSecondReport),null,dataSourceSecondReport);

    List list = new ArrayList(); 
    list.add(jasperPrint);
    list.add( jasperPrintSubReport );

    JRRtfExporter rtfExporter = new JRRtfExporter();
    rtfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, list);
    rtfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,pathOutputFile);
    System.out.println("Exporting report...");   
    rtfExporter.exportReport();
    System.out.println("Done!");
```

I created two jrxml file, the first one with vertical orientation and the second one with the horizontal orientation, but this doesn't work. The output file has an horizontal orientation.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the exporter from rtfExporter to docxExporter and now everything works